# After adding base tag in codeIgniter html a tag is not working How to solve this issue?

Tags: php, html, angularjs, codeigniter

I have an Angular one page application.For implementing this I am using `ng-route`. For making clean URLs, I use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and I added `<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">` in my header.php file.and the application is working correctly. But inner page a `left_menu` that is common for all the pages,  I have an edit button this should go to edit profile page. Here I have given  a normal a tag but this a tag is not working after adding base tag at the header.

Here is my controller.js code:

```
myapp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {           
            $routeProvider.

                when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: site_url+'welcome',
                    controller: 'homeController'
                }).
                when('/end', {
                    templateUrl: site_url+'result',
                    controller: 'endController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);    
        }]);
```

header.php:

```
<head>
   // included all needed script and css files
  <base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">
</head>
```

left_menu.php:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile">My Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>logout">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

After adding base tag in header left_menu `<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>` is not working.

Comment: How is your base_url is defined at `/application/config/config.php`?

Comment: hi base_url is defined as null like this $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: but after giving base url also it did not working

Answer (score 0):

On `application/config/autoload.php` you must load the URL helper. Search for a line like this:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array();
```

and change it to:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Can you set a `var_dump(base_url());` in your view and tell us what are you getting?

If it doesn't return anything you may set the base_url something like `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/yourprojectname';`

Comment: but its not redirecting.if i remove the base tag its working fine

Comment: but if i remove the base tag angularjs routing is not working

Comment: When you type on the browser `localhost/profile` you get the profile page or a 404?